# How to assign and save dataset in a loop, with names changing

Tags: r

I was trying to automate my calculation process due to memory constrain through below code but i am getting error in line 9 while saving the file in physical memory.

I have googled above query but didn't get any luck. I tried with 'get' function also but it prints the whole object on the screen.

```
m <- seq(0,nrow(Q_text),250)
m <- c(m,nrow(Q_text))
for(i in 1:(length(m)-1))
{
print(paste("processing form  ",m[i]+1," to ",m[i+1]))
data1 <- Q_text[(m[i]+1):m[i+1]]
assign(paste0("sentiment",i),calculate_sentiment(data1$feedback))
#### Below line not working
save(paste0("sentiment",i),file=paste0("sentiment_Q",i,".Rda"))
rm(data1,sentiment_Q_Inflight)
gc()
}
```

Getting below error:

```
Error in save(paste0("sentiment", i), file = paste0("sentiment_Q",  : 
object ‘paste0("sentiment", i)’ not found
```

Comment: What error are you getting exactly? Include the exact message as that seems to be relevant to your question.

Comment: use the `list` argument of `save`:  `save(list = paste0("sentiment", i), file = paste0("sentiment_Q", i, ".Rda"))`

Comment: @Peter Thanks, it worked!